finfo_file(C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Temp\phpAD40.tmp): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory
i got this error when i try to save uploaded file into model. i'm using codeigniter 4.5.2, what should i do to fix it?
public function store()
    {
        $getImage = $this->request->getFile('image');

        if ($getImage->getError() === 4) {
            if ($this->request->getPost('gender') == 'male') {
                $getImageName = "default_male.svg";
            } else {
                $getImageName = "default_female.svg";
            }
        } else {
            $getImageName = $getImage->getRandomName();
            $getImage->move('img/uploadedImg', $getImageName);
        }

        $data = [
            'name' => $this->request->getPost('name'),
            'email' => $this->request->getPost('email'),
            'username' => $this->request->getPost('username'),
            'gender' => $this->request->getPost('gender'),
            'major' => $this->request->getPost('major'),
            'address' => $this->request->getPost('address'),
            'phone' => $this->request->getPost('phone'),
            'image' => $getImageName
        ];

        if ($this->students->save($data) === false) {
            $errors = $this->students->errors();
            return redirect()->to('student/create')->withInput()->with('errors', $errors);
        } else {
            session()->setFlashdata('insert', 'student added!');
            return redirect()->to('student');
        }
    }

this my function.
i've been modify php.ini for upload_tmp_dir but it doesn't work
